# What if I don't have a column I can use as an aggregate function in my T-SQL PIVOT?

Tags: sql, pivot

As seen here: http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php

What if I don't have a column I can perform a SUM upon? How do I get a pivot'ed table result?

Comment: What do you plan to put in the rows and columns?

Comment: In the case of the example I linked to, I would be doing it the same way - but in my case, the field being SUMed is not a numeric value, its a string containing names.

Comment: I have posted a more explicit question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928162/how-do-i-pivot-this-in-t-sql

Comment: And as expected (though hoped otherwise) the aggregate is needed, but it's not always expected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928266/pivot-not-performing-as-expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always `COUNT(0)`, another option is to create a common table expression and create an extra column on top of your query with the appropriate value and then use that for the PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add a column with an alias and then refer to the alias, style:

select bar, baz, 0 as foo
from tabletable

Would that work?

Comment: What would that look like? In my example I always end up with numbers where the values should be.