# PIVOT not performing as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

Sorry for an unclear question previously; hopefully I can start again...

I have this data:

```
entityid    name                 stringvalue
----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           ShortDescription     Coal
1           LongDescription      BlackCoal
1           ShortDescription     Gold
1           LongDescription      WhiteGold
1           ShortDescription     Steel
1           LongDescription      StainlessSteel
```

And this query:

```
select *
from
(
    select entityid, name, stringvalue as stringvalue
    from mytable
) as d
pivot
(
    min([stringvalue])
    for [name] in ([ShortDescription],[LongDescription])
)
as p
```

Producing this output:

```
entityid ShortDescription LongDescription
-------- ---------------- ---------------
1        Coal             BlackCoal
```

Could someone tell me why the other rows are not being produced, please?  I was expecting to see:

```
entityid ShortDescription LongDescription
-------- ---------------- ---------------
1        Coal             BlackCoal
1        Gold             WhiteGold
1        Steel            StainlessSteel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be this:

```
select *
from
(
    select entityid, [name], stringvalue as stringvalue
    from mytable
) as d
pivot
(
    min(stringvalue)
    for [name] in ([ShortDescription],[LongDescription])
)
as p
```

:)

The flaw was that the input table should have had 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 for the entityid rows, respectively.

M